# Monitor Meteor pending requests

Tags: meteor

In a Meteor app, if the server is unreachable, all the pending requests are queued and resent when the server will be available again;
this is great, but I would like to:

- monitor the status of the connection, to show users that the app is currently offline
- notify the user about how many pending request are currently queued and monitor them in order to notify when are succesfully sent;

To be more clear I'd like to find a way to know how many pending request are currently queued (if any) and get informations about their status (to know when they are not more pending)

Comment: for the first one https://atmospherejs.com/francocatena/status there are many packages like this one

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: sorry but the request seems clear to me: I'd like to know if there is a way to know and monitor the pending requests (pending because the server is unreachable);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark Uretsky suggested, you can use a package like [francocatena:status](https://atmospherejs.com/francocatena/status) to get and display the status.

As for monitoring pending requests in his comment, there isn't a public API for that. However, it looks like currently you could use the [_methodInvokers](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L81) and/or [_outstandingMethodBlocks](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp-client/livedata_connection.js#L119) properties of `Meteor.connection` to determine which method calls are still outstanding.